# SQLAlchemy relationship raise Argument error when creating backref

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a one to many relationship so that each cafe can have many reviews. However, SQLAlchemy raises an `ArgumentError` when defining the relationship. How do I fix this error?

```
class Review(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cafe = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('cafe.name'))

class Cafe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    reviews = db.relationship(Review, backref='cafe')
```

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'cafe' on relationship 'Cafe.cafes': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Review|review'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When SQLAlchemy tries to create the backref for the `Cafe.cafes` relationship called `cafe` on `Review`, it finds the column you named `cafe` and raises an error that it can't use the same name.

Give your foreign keys different names than your relationships/backrefs.

```
cafe_name = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Cafe.name))
```

Alternatively, it can be easier to keep track of names when the foreign key and relationship are defined in the same model.

```
class Cafe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

class Review(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cafe_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Cafe.id))
    cafe = db.relationship(Cafe, backref='reviews')
```